# Monero project for charity/non-profit

Tags: mymonero, payment-integration, api

I wound like to create a "split the monero pot" for charity/non-profit organizations. 
The process for donating using XMR is easy, it's the people who don't have any crypto wallet to donate.

My thought would be to use MyMonero and exchange site via an API to convert the credit card info into XMR.

I checked the MyMonero site for features but I couldn't find any.  I read that MyMonero can create a wallet via an email address, is that correct?

The idea is for the credit card user to enter their email along with their credit/debit card information. Then the API would use the exchange to convert the money to xmr, then use My monero to create a wallet for the user so that if the user wins the pot, the system would send the coins to their new wallet, then email the user to notify them that they won. Then the user goes back to the site or clicks on the emailed link to determine if they want to convert/use the exchange to send it to their Bank account or keep the coins in their new wallet.

Can MM be used for that process?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without commenting on the idea... MyMonero is a web wallet which makes it easier for someone to have Monero. It is not a payment processor, which seems to be what you're after. So MyMonero isn't suitable.

Anything touching fiat money tends to be hard to get to due to regulations: most countries demand thorough spying on your customers, so many companies aren't able to withstand the costs of doing so. Something like https://bitpay.com may be close to what you're looking for, though they do settle in Bitcoin, not Monero. https://globee.com/ settles in Monero, but does not accept credit cards as far as I know. Maybe a combination of Bitpay and the API from https://shapeshift.io (to convert Bitcoin to Monero) might work for you ?